# type mismatch; found : String required: Int

Tags: string

I wrote a program which processes a string using functional programming style. It gives an odd "type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int" error on this line `else if(c==('s')) helper1(s(str), s.drop(1))`. Thanks in advance.

```
 def stringpipeline(string:String) : (String) => String = { 
  def r(s:String):String = {s.reverse}
  def s(s:String) = {s.sorted}
  def U(s:String) = {s.toUpperCase}
  def l(s:String) = {s.toLowerCase}
  def star(s:String):String = {s.trim}
  def T(s:String):String = {s.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")}
  def helper1(str:String, s:String): String = {
    if (s.length != 0)
    {

        val c = s(0)

        if(c==('T')) helper1(T(str), s.drop(1))

        if(c==('s')) helper1(s(str), s.drop(1))

        if(c==('*')) helper1(star(str),s.drop(1))

        else str
    }

    else str
  }

  def helper2(strn:String): String = {helper1(strn,string)}
  helper2 _ 

}
```

Comment: You have a method called `s` and also a string called `s`. When you are doing `s(str)` you are not calling the method `s`, you are calling a method on the string `s`. I would suggest renaming your method `s` to something more meaningful like `sort`.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
helper1(s(str), s.drop(1))
```

In code `s(str)` you're calling `String.apply(Int)` method. `str` is `String`, so compiler notifies about it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have declared `s` in two different scopes.  In the overall scope you have declared `s` as a method which acts on a String and returns a String.  In the scope of `helper1()` you have also declared `s` as a String parameter.  This declaration overrides (shadows) the declaration of the method `s` outside `helper1()`.

Where the error is reported, you are trying to use the method `s(str)`, but the compiler is picking up the declaration `s:String`.  You should fix this by renaming the name of either the method or the parameter.  In general I would suggest avoiding single character names for methods, parameters or variables and instead using longer and more descriptive names - this is not a requirement to fix this problem, but you would have been more likely to avoid it by using, for example, `sorted()`.